# Is there a way for typescript to infer arguments object or have a type defined for arguments object?

Tags: typescript

I have a type like the following:

```
type success = (data: any, value: string, settings: any) => void
```

OR an interface like the following

```
// interface success { (data: any, value: string, settings: any): void }
```

I have an object like this
`{ onSuccess: (<need to have 'success' type here for arguments>) => { callbackFunction(<call using the same arguments passed to OnSuccess function>) } }`

- Is there a way to have `arguments` object passed to `onSuccess` function be type inferred to `success` type? If so how do I define an `interface` or a `type` signature similar to `success` type above that can be used to be type inferred?

Comment: Avoid arguments keyword as much as possible

Comment: what is the signature of the callbackFunction ?

Comment: @MichelVorwieger The callbackFuntion expects the following `callbackFunction(data: any, value: string, settings: any)`. 

If you notice, the arguments signature is the same as the `success` type above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the built-in `Parameters`

```js
type success = (data: any, value: string, settings: any) => void

const fn = (...args: Parameters<success>) => {}
```

Comment: Thanks! This was what I was looking for. Did not know there was `Parameters` available

Answer (score 0):

if the order of the object arguments are always the same you might be able todo something with `Object.values` and the spread operator

`Object.values`: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

```
> const fn = (a, b, c) => ({a,b,c})
undefined
> fn({a: 5, b: 3, c:2})
{ a: { a: 5, b: 3, c: 2 }, b: undefined, c: undefined }
> fn(...Object.values({a: 5, b: 3, c: 2}))
{ a: 5, b: 3, c: 2 }
```

where `Object.values({a: 5, b: 3, c: 2})`  is equal to `[5, 3, 2]`

Although I would not recommend this and would just add some code to map them directly to prevent bugs later on.